# Rendering csv data line-by-line without writing file

Tags: python, csv

I want to change a large CSV-file and write result into new file.

My python script `run.py`:

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open(..., 'w'))
for l in csv.reader(open(...)):
    l[0] = 'foo' if l[1] else 'bar'
    writer.writerow(l)
```

I've realize that more suitable for me write file using Linux `pipe`:

```
run.py > new-csv-file.csv
```

I've written:

```
import csv
import io
s = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(s)
for l in csv.reader(open(...)):
    l[0] = 'foo' if l[1] else 'bar'
    writer.writerow(l)
    print(s.getvalue())
```

It's wrong code. Each cycle appends new line in `s` and prints whole file content on each cycle, not line-by-line.

How can I clean `s` on each cycle?
Or how can I render csv-string line-by-line?

```
for l in csv.reader(open(...)):
    l[0] = 'foo' if l[1] else 'bar'
    s = my_imaginary_csv_render(l)
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understand you correct you want that your code,
instead of file print to stdout?
Here solution:

```
import csv

for l in csv.reader(open(...)):
   l[0] = 'foo' if l[1] else 'bar'
   print(", ".join(l))
```

This solution not works as expected if data fields contain line separators,
then to not duplicate csv logic for escaping special symbols in csv you can use:

```
csv.writer(sys.stdout)
```

Comment: It was my first solution, but `l[:]` contains commas, and I have to use `csv.writer`.

Comment: Then just use csv.writer(sys.stdout)